# What's required to make mockMVC test a filter's init routine?

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mocking, servlet-filters

I have implemented the following CORS filter, which works when the code is executed on the server:

```
/*
 *    Copyright 2013 BrandsEye (http://www.brandseye.com)
 *
 *    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *    You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *    limitations under the License.
 */

package org.energyos.espi.datacustodian.web.filter;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * Adds CORS headers to requests to enable cross-domain access.
 */

@Component
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    private final Map<String, String> optionsHeaders = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    private Pattern allowOriginRegex;
    private String allowOrigin;
    private String exposeHeaders;

    public void init(FilterConfig cfg) throws ServletException {
        String regex = cfg.getInitParameter("allow.origin.regex");
        if (regex != null) {
            allowOriginRegex = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        } else {
            optionsHeaders.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }

        optionsHeaders.put("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Authorization, Accept, Content-Type");
        optionsHeaders.put("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        optionsHeaders.put("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1800");
        for (Enumeration<String> i = cfg.getInitParameterNames(); i.hasMoreElements(); ) {
            String name = i.nextElement();
            if (name.startsWith("header:")) {
                optionsHeaders.put(name.substring(7), cfg.getInitParameter(name));
            }
        }

        //maintained for backward compatibility on how to set allowOrigin if not
        //using a regex
        allowOrigin = optionsHeaders.get("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
        //since all methods now go through checkOrigin() to apply the Access-Control-Allow-Origin
        //header, and that header should have a single value of the requesting Origin since
        //Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is always true, we remove it from the options headers
        optionsHeaders.remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");

        exposeHeaders = cfg.getInitParameter("expose.headers");
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {          
            logger.debug("CORSFilter processing: Checking for Cross Origin pre-flight OPTIONS message");
        }

        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest && response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)response;
            if ("OPTIONS".equals(req.getMethod())) {
                allowOrigin = "*";                                          //%%%%% Test force of allowOrigin
                if (checkOrigin(req, resp)) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : optionsHeaders.entrySet()) {
                        resp.addHeader(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
                    }

                    // We need to return here since we don't want the chain to further process
                    // a preflight request since this can lead to unexpected processing of the preflighted
                    // request or a 40x - Response Code
                    return;

                }
            } else if (checkOrigin(req, resp)) {
                if (exposeHeaders != null) {
                    resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", exposeHeaders);
                }
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    private boolean checkOrigin(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");
        if (origin == null) {
            //no origin; per W3C specification, terminate further processing for both pre-flight and actual requests
            return false;
        }

        boolean matches = false;
        //check if using regex to match origin
        if (allowOriginRegex != null) {
            matches = allowOriginRegex.matcher(origin).matches();
        } else if (allowOrigin != null) {
            matches = allowOrigin.equals("*") || allowOrigin.equals(origin);
        }

        if (matches) {

            // Activate next two lines and comment out third line if Credential Support is required
//          resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
//          resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");         
            resp.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

The following JUnit test uses mockMVC  but fails, because the CORSFilter's "init" logic is not being executed (proven by breakpointing the JUnit test):

```
package org.energyos.espi.datacustodian.integration.web.filters;


import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;

import org.energyos.espi.datacustodian.web.filter.CORSFilter;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.options;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.header;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("/spring/test-context.xml")
@Profile("test")
public class CORSFilterTests {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());   

    @Autowired
    private CORSFilter filter;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
                .addFilters(filter).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void optionsResponse_hasCorrectFilters() throws Exception {

        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.options("/DataCustodian/oauth/token")
                .header("Origin", "foobar")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 

        MvcResult result =   mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(header().string("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", is("*")))
                .andExpect(header().string("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", is("GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS")))
                .andExpect(header().string("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", is("origin, authorization, accept, content-type")))
                .andExpect(header().string("Access-Control-Max-Age", is("1800")))               
                .andReturn();      
        }
    }
}
```

I have reviewed the available material on the internet, which seems to imply the ".addfilter(filter). element of the mockMVC @Before section should be executing the CORSFilter init routine.  However, that is clearly NOT happening.

Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated, as I am really stuck understanding how to get the "init" routine tested using the mockMVC capability.

Comment: HI! do you have any solution for his issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774909/how-to-bypass-or-skip-customfilter-in-mockito-with-springboot-applicaiton .      any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The Spring MVC Test suite is not meant to test the container configuration, it is meant to test your MVC (`@Controller` and other mappings) configuration . `Filter#init(ServletConfig)` is a container managed method.

If you really need to test it, you can mock that too

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    filter.init(someMockFilterConfig); // using a mock that you construct with init params and all
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
            .addFilters(filter).build();
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to implement the fix you suggested but would like to accept your answer, but I am not sure how to do that (sorry this is my first posting).     I made the CORSFilter check for an origin of "JUnit_Test" and then provide the data the CORSFilter init routine provides when the filter is loaded by the server.  I'd like to understand the solution you suggested, but since it essentially does the same as the code I added, I took a shortcut to save time.

Comment: @donald I assumed too much from your question. You can _mock_ objects with libraries like [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/). These mocked objects exhibit the behaviour you want them to. For example, a `Filter` would need the whole servlet container, but not with mocks. Check out the examples in the link and others around the net. If you want to accept my answer, you can check the checkmark next to my answer's score.

Answer (score 8):

After lots of tests, here's what we adopted:

- for testing a `@RestController` use MockMvc.
- for testing a Filter or other infrastructure elements, use `TestRestTemplate`.

With MockMvc, `addFilter(Filter)` did not result in the execution of the filter at all. The solution with `TestRestTemplate` is more primitive, but all Filters configured in your application/libraries are executed. Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = MySpringBootApplication.class, webEnvironment= 
SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyRestControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Test
    public void myTestCase() throws Exception {

        HttpStatus expectedStatusCode = HttpStatus.OK;
        String expectedResponseBody = "{\"someProperty\" : \"someValue\" }";

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer YourTokenJwtForExample");

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);

        TestRestTemplate restTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            "http://localhost:" + port + "/my-rest-uri",
            HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);

        Assert.assertEquals(expectedStatusCode, response.getStatusCode());
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedResponseBody, response.getBody());
    }

}
```

Comment: If you autowire in `TestRestTemplate` you can ommit host and port.

Comment: @Paulo Merson I have similar issue with Filters. Can you please check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74203660/unable-to-inject-custom-filter-while-performing-integration-testing-using-spring

Answer (score 3):

For a `Spring Boot` app, if `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` is used then filter.init() is called automatically. if `@SpringBootTest` is used with default parameters then filter.init() needs to be invoked manually.

Comment: This is the easiest solution

Answer (score 2):

If you want a true unit test instead of an integration test, you may also want to take a look at `org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletConfig` available from

`org.springframework:spring-test` maven artifact

You can set up config parameters on the mock object.  There are also mocks for HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse and FilterChain