# Spring filter chain is not applied on unit test MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

I made a custom filter and registered on WebConfig, but when I call the api, the filter does not get invoked. I looked through the log, and seems like filter chain I described on the config is not applied. However I checked WebConfig is invoked using debugger.

```java
//MyFilter.java
@Component
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  doFilter(...) { // This part is NOT getting invoked
    ...
  }
}
```

```java
//WebConfig.java
@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> myFilter() { // This part is getting invoked
    regBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    regBean.setFilter(new MyFilter());
    regBean.setOrder(0);
    return regBean;
  }
}
```

```java
//MyTest.java
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class MyTest {
  
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Autowired
  WebApplicationContext ctx;

  @Before
  public void before() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationSetup(ctx).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void doTest() {
    mockMvc.perform(...);
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove `@ContextConfiguration`, add `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`. Ditch the `@Before` annotated method and add `@Autowired` to the `MockMvc` field. Then re-run the test.

Comment: Removing `@ContextConfiguration` causes `IllegalStateException` so I can't run the test without it.

Comment: Which is weird as it should automatically detect the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class (unless you have some weirdish non standard packaging structure). Could you add the exception (the **full exception stacktrace**) to your question as an update.

Comment: In your test is this really? `@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)` or `@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfig.class)` or is it just an example you posted ?

Comment: It is better to use @AutoConfiguraMockMvc and you can autowire it in integration-test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationSetup(ctx)
            .addFilters(filter).build();
```

If you don't use `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` then you have to add filters to mockMvc builder.

[What's required to make mockMVC test a filter's init routine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20819130/whats-required-to-make-mockmvc-test-a-filters-init-routine)

Also there is a configuration problem here.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<MyFilter> myFilter(MyFilter myfilter) { // This part is getting invoked
    regBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    regBean.setFilter(myFilter);
    regBean.setOrder(0);
    return regBean;
}
```

You are putting new Instance of a filter to filter chain but you create singleton filter. You can use above configuration.

Comment: Credits on the `FilterRegistrationBean` he now actually adds 2 filters to the chain. However when using `@SpringBootTest` you should use `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` so that the proper configuration of filters etc. gets applied.

Comment: I added this line of sentences : "If you don't use @AutoConfiguraMockMvc then you have to add filters to mockMvc builder."

Comment: For me it worked only with @Import( MyConfigClassName.class) at the test class level.